# Removing outliers from a dataframe using boxplot function

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

I want to remove from my dataframe all the observations where at least one variable is beyond 2 standard deviations. I've got 38 variables plus two others columns.

These lines extract the outliers:

```
std=2
outliers = boxplot(data[3:40], plot=FALSE,range=std)$out
```

but I can't update my dataframe, I tried a bunch of things like:

```
data[3:40][!data[3:40] %in% outliers]
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: I usually use ggplot, but looking at `?boxplot` : maybe try `outline = FALSE`

Comment: What's `data`?? Please provide [Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: data is a dataset with 40 columns, but I have found a solution to my problem

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and mark it correct, not editing your question to add it in

Answer (score 0):

@mobupu Tjebo is right. `boxplot(x, outline = FALSE)` removes outliers. 
this is a simple reproducible example.

```
i<-iris$Sepal.Length
i[151]<-25
boxplot(i)
boxplot(i, outline = FALSE)
```

Comment: actually i want to remove the outliers from my dataframe, not from the boxplot. I speak about boxplot because `boxplot(data[3:40], plot=FALSE,range=std)$out` return the list of outliers value, that i want to match in my dataframe to remove the corresponding rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove rows where any variable in columns 3:40 is > 2 stdev from the mean with

```
require(magrittr); require(dplyr)
df %<>%  .[sapply(.[ ,3:40], function(x) x %between% (mean(x) + 2*c(-1, 1)*sd(x))) %>% 
            apply(1, all)
        ,]
```